# How to use promises with async/await and for loop in js

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
  find_drives: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user_location = req.query.user_location;
      const user_destination = req.query.user_destination;

      const drives = await Drive.find({ status: "open" }).lean();
      drives.forEach((drive) => {
        getTravelStats(user_location, drive.departure_location).then(
          (stats) => (drive.start_stats = stats)
        );
        getTravelStats(user_destination, drive.arrival_location).then(
          (stats) => (drive.end_stats = stats)
        );
      });
      res.status(200).json(drives);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
    }
  },
```

The `start_stats` and `end_stats` properties don't get set, but when I log the `stats` it works. I think the problem is with how I'm using promises, how would I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Array#forEach` does not support `async` functions, you can use `for of`:

```js
for (const drive of drives) {
    drive.start_stats = await getTravelStats(user_location, drive.departure_location);
    drive.end_stats = await getTravelStats(user_destination, drive.arrival_location);
}
```

If you want to call `getTravelStats` in parallel for all drivers:

```
await Promise.all(drives.map(async (drive) => {
    drive.start_stats = await getTravelStats(user_location, drive.departure_location);
    drive.end_stats = await getTravelStats(user_destination, drive.arrival_location);
}));
```

Comment: Is the second way better?